# Why are my dicts alternating between mutable and immutable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, immutability, mutable

Consider this code

```
from pprint import pprint
test_dict = {}
new = {}
new['slot'] = {}
for k in range(5):
    test_dict[k] = {}
    test_dict[k].update(new)
    if k == 3:
        test_dict[k]['slot']['this should only be in 3'] = []
pprint(test_dict)
print('Round 2, without SLOT')
test_dict = {}
new = {}
for k in range(5):
    test_dict[k] = {}
    test_dict[k].update(new)
    if k == 3:
        test_dict[k]['this should only be in 3'] = []
pprint(test_dict)
```

With this output

```
> python -i .\test2.py
{0: {'slot': {'this should only be in 3': []}},
 1: {'slot': {'this should only be in 3': []}},
 2: {'slot': {'this should only be in 3': []}},
 3: {'slot': {'this should only be in 3': []}},
 4: {'slot': {'this should only be in 3': []}}}
Round 2, without SLOT
{0: {}, 1: {}, 2: {}, 3: {'this should only be in 3': []}, 4: {}}
```

Help me understand why in the first case, the **'should only be...'** list is appearing in every case and not the second. Dicts are immutable but I don't understand why I'm getting different results.

Thanks,

Comment: You set `new['slot']` to an empty dictionary. Then you reference that dictionary in multiple other containers (by `.update(new)`). Then you mutate it. Dicts are *not* immutable.

Comment: *"Dicts are immutable but I don't understand why I'm getting different results."* This is a false claim. The `new['slot']` dict is very mutable.

Comment: Ok, the last thing I don't understand is why it's not happening in the second test. I'm copying a dict in both cases, the only difference is that in Test 1, the 'slot' dict is added to 'new'.

Comment: Let me expand on that. 

If I print(id) for everything in test 1, test_dict[k] has a unique ID for every iteration, but test_dict[k]['slot'] is identical every time. I don't understand this phenomenon. To me they should either all be identical, or all unique.

Answer (score 1):

You are storing the same instance of the `dict` stored in `new['slot']` in each key of `test_dict`:

```py
from pprint import pprint
test_dict = {}
new = {}
new['slot'] = {}
new['slot']['id'] = id(new['slot'])
for k in range(5):
    test_dict[k] = {}
    test_dict[k].update(new)
    if k == 3:
        test_dict[k]['slot']['this should only be in 3'] = []
pprint(test_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{0: {'slot': {'id': 4433735760, 'this should only be in 3': []}},
 1: {'slot': {'id': 4433735760, 'this should only be in 3': []}},
 2: {'slot': {'id': 4433735760, 'this should only be in 3': []}},
 3: {'slot': {'id': 4433735760, 'this should only be in 3': []}},
 4: {'slot': {'id': 4433735760, 'this should only be in 3': []}}}
```

A possible fix would be to create a new `dict` each time you need one:

```py
from pprint import pprint
test_dict = {}
for k in range(5):
    test_dict[k] = {}
    new = {'slot': dict()}
    new['slot']['id'] = id(new['slot'])
    test_dict[k].update(new)
    if k == 3:
        test_dict[k]['slot']['this should only be in 3'] = []
pprint(test_dict)
```

**Output**

```
{0: {'slot': {'id': 4399711968}},
 1: {'slot': {'id': 4399712528}},
 2: {'slot': {'id': 4399713088}},
 3: {'slot': {'id': 4399713648, 'this should only be in 3': []}},
 4: {'slot': {'id': 4399730768}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `update` method does not make a copy of `new['slot']` for each entry in `test_dict`.

After

```
test_dict = {}
new = {}
new['slot'] = {}
for k in range(5):
    test_dict[k] = {}
    test_dict[k].update(new)
    if k == 3:
        test_dict[k]['slot']['this should only be in 3'] = []
```

`test_dict[k]['slot']` is a reference to the same `dict` for each `k = 0, 1, ..., 4`. You can confirm this with `id`:

```
>>> for k in range(5): id(test_dict[k]['slot'])
...
4422633104
4422633104
4422633104
4422633104
4422633104
>>> id(new['slot'])
4422633104
```

Comment: So you're saying if I do update(new), I'm creating a new 'new' dict. But if I write update(new['slot']), I'm inserting that same copy of 'slot' every time.

Comment: No, `test_dict[k].update(new)` is essentially just a wrapper around `for i in new: test_dict[k][i] = new[i]`. The only thing new that might be created is a new key in `test_dict[k]`.